# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) filtering value from other table mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT name 
FROM tabel 
WHERE n1 IN (
      SELECT key1,key2,key3 
      FROM tabel2
)
```

but if try :

```
SELECT name 
FROM tabel 
WHERE n1 IN ('1','2','5')
```

its work

thanks

Comment: Against _which_ key are you trying to match `n1`?  Is it `key1`, `key2`, or `key3`?

Comment: `IN (SELECT key1,key2,key3 FROM tabel2)` is a set of **1+** row (with 3 columns). `WHERE n1 IN ('1','2','5')` is a set of **3** rows. They are two completely different things. IN requires a set of values (1 "column")

Comment: You could JOIN the tables with ...table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name IN (t2.key1, t2.key2, t2.key3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use queries which return more than 1 column if you want to use the result in an IN clause

Try something like this if you want to match against all 3 Keys:

```
SELECT name FROM tabel 
WHERE n1 IN (SELECT key1 FROM tabel2)
OR n1 IN (SELECT key2 FROM tabel2)
OR n1 IN (SELECT key3 FROM tabel2)
```

**Explanation:**
This works because its a list of values:

```
WHERE n1 IN ('1','2','3')
```

This does not work:

```
WHERE n1 IN (SELECT key1, key2, key3 FROM tabel2)
```

The query returns a list of results instead of single values:

```
WHERE n1 IN (('1','5',',7'),('2','8',',72'),('11','52',',72'))
```

Comment: I guess JOIN will be faster than executing multiple queries

Comment: You are probably right. I just find it way more readable